# High Heap usage in nodejs express application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I'm new to Nodejs. I have created a script which will upload file to server. When I try to run with "pm2 start app.js". I get active handles - 4, and heap usage above 80% without running any request. Can someone suggest guidelines to follow to avoid such issues and how to make it scalable. I tried to take heap snapshots using chrome dev tools. But couldn't understand it.

Snapshot1 - 7.3MB (without hitting any request)

Snapshot2 - 13MB (hitting 8-9 requests)

system / JSArrayBufferData×2 - 37 % (shallow size)

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const _ = require('lodash');

const app = express();

const config = require('./config');
const { HTTP_PORT } = config.env;
const { filesize , audiosize, uploadfilepath, uploadaudiopath} = config.file;

var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path')

// enable css and js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));


// enable files upload
app.use(fileUpload({
    createParentPath: true,
}));

//add other middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.post('/upload/file', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        if(!req.files) {
            res.send({
                status: false,
                message: 'No file uploaded'
            });
        } else {
            //Use the name of the input field (i.e. "avatar") to retrieve the uploaded file
            let avatar = req.files.file_upload;
            let id = req.body.userid;
            id = (id === undefined) ? "default" : id;

            // Checking File Size (Max Size - 5MB)
            if(avatar.size > filesize){
        
                return res.send({
                    status: 413,
                    message: 'file size greater than 5mb'
                });
            }
            
            //Use the mv() method to place the file in upload directory (i.e. "uploads")
            try {
                avatar.mv(uploadfilepath +`/${id}_` + avatar.name);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                return res.send({
                    status: 413,
                    message: "file couldn't be uploaded"
                });
            }
            
            //send response
            res.send({
                status: true,
                message: 'File is uploaded',
            });
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send(err);
    }
});

http.createServer(app).listen(HTTP_PORT, () => 
console.log(`HTTP App is listening on port ${process.env.HTTP_PORT}`));
```

Comment: This maybe gonna reduce the heap usage, don’t import `lodash` like that, it’s huge (if you don’t really use all of it and you enable tree shaking in case you use some bundler it probably won’t matter), import specific function like [`lodash.omit`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.omit)

Comment: Try running Node in production mode? `NODE_ENV="production"`. You can also replace `body-parser` with Express's own (https://dev.to/taylorbeeston/you-probably-don-t-need-body-parser-in-your-express-apps-3nio). As @RazLuvaton said, import only the parts of Lodash you really need (I personally don't think you need Lodash at all; arrays and objects already have plenty of native methods for manipulation)

Comment: Is your heap usage really 7.3MB and 13MB?  That's very small.  I don't see what the problem would be?  You should have several GB of free memory to use.

Comment: Jeremy, I really don’t like `lodash` ever since [lodash#5136](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/5136)

Comment: thanks @RazLuvaton I will remove lodash and body parser. The thing is when I deploy it in windows server IIS it takes about a minute to upload a 4mb file.

Comment: @jfriend00 then why "pm2 monit" is showing heap usage 86%

Comment: It appears that "heap usage" just means that of the heap space allocated from the OS by nodejs, it is using 86% of it and 14% of it is available for future use by nodejs.  That is perfectly fine and expected.